# php form action path with variable

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm really thinking I must have a badly formed php echo statement at the beginning of the  but Dreamweaver is telling me that I have no syntax errors. My process.php is never getting called.

```
 $file = dirname(__FILE__) . '/customBook-index.php';
 $plugin_path = plugin_dir_path($file);
 $plugin_url = plugin_dir_url($file);

 <?php

     echo '<form method="post" action="'.$plugin_url.'process.php" />';

         echo'<select name="clients">';
        foreach($clientsArray as $client){
             echo'<option value="'.$client.'">'.$client.'</option>';
         }
     echo'</select>';
     echo '</form>';
    ?>
```

Comment: How is the form submitted?  I am not seeing any submit button or javascript.  Also to @Bruno Vieira's point - what is that random "a" character doing before the closing brace?

Comment: the random "a" character was a typo in my post and not my code. I would like to process the form with php if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to `echo` all of your HTML. You could also write:

```
<?php
    $file = dirname(__FILE__) . '/customBook-index.php';
    $plugin_path = plugin_dir_path($file);
    $plugin_url = plugin_dir_url($file);
?>
<form method="post" action="<?=$plugin_url?>process.php" />
    <select name="clients">
        <?php
            foreach($clientsArray as $client){
                ?>
                <option value="<?=$client?>"><?=$client?></option>
                <?php
            }
        ?>
    </select>
</form>
```

Maybe that's easier for you to read and understand!? What is the output of `$plugin_url.'process.php` in your HTML? I think that either the path does not match or that you don't submit your form correctly.